# Discord.js media channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to add a media only channel to my discord.js bot. I want people to be able to send only links and images. I've made the image part of the channel but when users send links my bot delete them. For example `prnt.sc/xxxxx`.

Here is my code :

```
bot.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.channel.id !== "815002698499096616") { 
      return;
    }

    // Checking if the author is a bot.
    if (msg.author.bot) {
        return false;
    }

    // Deleting the message if there are 0 attachments in the message.
    if (msg.attachments.size == 0) {
        msg.delete();
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: No.. i want to make photos and links channel

Comment: And by the looks of it you've already figured out how to check if the message has an attachment, so the next step would be to use a regex to figure out if the message contains a link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regex like this:

```
var isLink = /^http/g
console.log(isLink.test("https://example.com")) // returns true

if(msg.attachments.size == 0 || !isLink.test(text content of your message)) {
    msg.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all helpers <3 I wrote a new code and it's works :) Here is my code:

```
 bot.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.channel.id !== "804813461309620316") { 
      return;
    }
    // Checking if the author is a bot.
    if (msg.author.bot) return false;

    if (msg.content.includes('.png')) return false;

    if (msg.content.includes('.jpg')) return false;

    if (msg.content.includes('.jpeg')) return false;

    if (msg.content.includes('prnt.sc')) return false;
   
    // Deleting the message if there are 0 attachments in the message.
    if (msg.attachments.size == 0) msg.delete()
});
```